# Problema con una subscripción en un servicio - angular cli

Tags: php, angular, angular-cli

aqui necesito de su ayuda espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano.

Tengo el siguiente problema:
En la imagen 1 esta mis servicios, estos los consumo desde php. (El primero es para registrar y el segundo es para listar a los clientes).

```
RegistrarClienteJuridico(cliente) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.url}insertar_cliente_juridico.php`, JSON.stringify(cliente));
}

// LISTAR CLIENTES
ListarClientes(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}listar_clientes.php`)
}
```

-> y aquí es donde los cargo, con este método:( ya intente eliminar la suscripción pero nada).

```
ObtenerDatosClientes(id: number): void {
      //this.subscripcion.add(
        this.ServicioCliente.SeleccionarClienteJuridico(id).subscribe(result => this.clie = result[0]);
      //  );
  }
```

Les comento para registrar los clientes si esta todo bien el problema viene cuando yo paso datos de los clientes al formulario, y si después quiero registrar a otro cliente me arroja el siguiente error.

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'resultadocj' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (clientejuridico.component.ts:161)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:70)
```

Y me redirige aca
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

```
  RegistrarClientes = async () => {

    const pass = this.clie.clave;
    let PassEncriptada = await this.r_pass_encrip.EncriptarClaveCliente(pass);
    console.log("1: " + PassEncriptada)

    Swal.fire({
      title: '¿Esta seguro de registrar este cliente?',
      icon: 'question',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: `Si, estoy seguro`,
      cancelButtonText: `Cancelar`
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        console.log("==> " + PassEncriptada)

        this.AlertasService.Cargando_ESpere();

        this.clie.claveencriptada = PassEncriptada;
        this.ServicioCliente.RegistrarClienteJuridico(this.clie).subscribe(datoscj => {

          if (datoscj['resultadocj'] == 'OK') {

            Swal.fire('Registrado satisfactoriamente', '', 'success')

          } else if (datoscj['resultadocj'] == 'FAIL') {
            Swal.fire('NO SE HA PODIDO REGISTRAR', '', 'warning')
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

En si si me registra satisfactoriamente pero no me retorna los mensajes de confirmación, alguien sabrá por que?

Comment: Hola, por favor no utilices imágenes para mostrar tu código. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código como texto. Asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: ya lo hice bro! me ayudas?

Comment: Gracias por la correción! No entiendo bien cuál es el problema. Podrías agregar el código completo de los componentes y servicios en donde tienes el problema?

Comment: En esta linea `if (datoscj['resultadocj'] == 'OK') {...`, `datoscj` esta vacío. Esto se puede debuguear poniendo antes de la linea `console.log(datoscj)`. Por favor haz esta prueba y comenta lo que te arroje la consola.

Comment: ya imprimi en consola, pero me sale "null"

Comment: {resultadocj: "OK", mensaje: "datos grabados"}
mensaje: "datos grabados"
resultadocj: "OK"
__proto__: Object

Pero si registro directamente sin traer datos, si me retorna los mensajes de confirmacion

Comment: ¿si pruebas el mismo servicio desde postman o algo similar te da respuesta? Porque parece que tu servicio no responde.

Comment: Si ya lo probé desde postman y ambos funcionan correctamente!